# Struct containing vector of pointers to other structs

Tags: c++, memory, vector, struct

I have a little complicated data structure but I have a problem with insertion to it, maybe I am thinking wrong.
This data structure is something like (we have a map which is a pair of uint16_t and structure, and three nested structures)

```
struct Struct4
{
  uint8_t  struct4ByteData1;
  uint8_t  struct4ByteData2;
  uint16_t struct4ShortIntData1;
  uint16_t struct4ShortIntData2;
};
struct Struct3
{
  uint32_t    struct3IntData1; 
  uint16_t    struct3ShortIntData1;
  uint16_t    numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4;
  std::string struct3StringData;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Struct4>> struct4vector;
};
struct Struct2 
{
  uint32_t    struct2IntData1; 
  uint16_t    struct2ShortIntData1;
  uint16_t    numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct3;
  int16_t     struct2ShortIntData2;
  std::string struct2StringData;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Struct3>> struct3vector;
};
struct Struct1
{
  uint32_t  struct1IntData1;
  uint16_t  numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct2;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Struct2>> struct2vector;
};

using uint16AndStruct1Map = std::multimap<uint16_t, Struct1>;
```

And here is a code snippet how data is inserted:

```
Struct1* struct1_ptr = new Struct1;
std::shared_ptr<Struct2> vectorOfStruct2;
std::shared_ptr<Struct3> vectorOfStruct3;
std::shared_ptr<Struct4> vectorOfStruct4;

uint16AndStruct1Map mapToBeInserted;

bool validData = false;

uint16_t numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4;
uint16_t status;
uint16_t keyDataFromStruct2;

struct1_ptr->struct1IntData1 = getSomeData();
struct1_ptr->numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct2 = getSomeElements();

if (struct1_ptr->numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct2 == 0)
{
  std::cout << "No Pim Avoidance Measurement in This Message, ignore" << std::endl;
  return;
}
for(uint16_t i = 0; i < getNumOfElementsOfStruct2(); i++)
{

  vectorOfStruct2 = std::make_shared<vectorOfStruct2>();

  keyDataFromStruct2 = getKey();
  vectorOfStruct2->struct2IntData1 = getSomeData();
  vectorOfStruct2->struct2ShortIntData1 = keyDataFromStruct2;
  vectorOfStruct2->struct2ShortIntData2 = getSomeData();
  vectorOfStruct2->numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct3 = getSomeElements();
  vectorOfStruct2->struct2StringData = getSomeStringData();

  struct1_ptr->struct2vector.push_back(vectorOfStruct2);

  for(uint16_t j = 0; j < getNumOfElementsOfStruct3(); j++)
  {

    vectorOfStruct3 = std::make_shared<vectorOfStruct3>();

    vectorOfStruct3->struct3IntData1 = getSomeData();
    vectorOfStruct3->struct3ShortIntData1 = getSomeData();
    vectorOfStruct3->numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4 = getSomeElements();
    vectorOfStruct3->struct3StringData = getSomeStringData();

    struct1_ptr->struct2vector[i]->struct3vector.push_back(vectorOfStruct3);

    numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4 = getNumOfElementsOfStruct4();

    if(numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4 < 10)
    {
      for(uint16_t k = 0; k < numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4; k++)
      {
        vectorOfStruct4 = std::make_shared<vectorOfStruct4>();
        status = getStatus();
        if(status == SPECIAL_STATUS_TO_GET_INSIDE_THIS_IF_COND)
        {
          vectorOfStruct4->struct4ByteData1 = getSomeData();
          vectorOfStruct4->struct4ByteData2 = getSomeData();
          vectorOfStruct4->struct4ShortIntData1 = getSomeData();
          vectorOfStruct4->struct4ShortIntData2 = status;

          struct1_ptr->struct2vector[i]->struct3vector->struct4vector.push_back(vectorOfStruct4);
          validData = true;
        }
      }
     }
   }

  if(validData)
  {
    mapToBeInserted.insert (std::make_pair(keyDataFromStruct2,*struct1_ptr));
  }
  else
  {
    for (auto it = mapToBeInserted.begin(); it!=mapToBeInserted.end(); it++)
    {
      it->second.numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct2--;
    }
  }
  validData = false;
}
```

After everything was inserted into map (and all of structures), when I want to get data from this map I probably get memory error. I am not 100% sure what the problem is.
The issue occurs at level of obtaining data from the map: mapToBeInserted.

Could you help?

Comment: Where is the code for reading from the map? We need a [mcve]

Comment: The instruction `struct1_ptr->struct2vector[i]->struct3vector->struct4vector.push_back(vectorOfStruct4);` is correct ? it should be `struct1_ptr->struct2vector[i]->struct3vector[j]->struct4vector.push_back(vectorOfStruct4);` ?

Comment: Ahh, right, my mistake - it is not copied, I modified a little so I cut a little.

Answer (score 0):

if `numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4` is more than 10 you don't insert anything into `struct4vector` therefore this loop will access out of the bounds of `struct4vector`:

```
for(uint16_t l = 0; l < kv.second.struct2vector[j]->struct3vector[k]->numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4; l++) 
      {
        ss << "<"
        << kv.second.struct2vector[j]->struct3vector[k]->struct4vector[l]->struct4ByteData1 << ","
```

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing wrong with the map insertion. The program crashed because of the vector index numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4.

You have set the number of element :

`vectorOfStruct3->numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4 = getSomeElements();`

But the data of struct4vector is inserted with CONDITION (there are two : < 10 and Status is OK)

So that the vector size  struct4vector.size() and numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4 can be different (when numOfElementsInVectorOfStruct4 < 10 and 
one of its element has status OK).

Here are some advices :

- Work with pointer (with map) to avoid the struct element copy
- Work with vector size() function instead of getSomeElements() somewhere.
- Check for the map element exists before used